# making a PCI soundcard work inside a Parallels Desktop virtual machine

Tags: windows, macos, virtual-machine, sound-card, parallels

im running Windows 8.1 inside Parallels Desktop 9 in Mavericks (mac)

I have an **ASUS Xonar Essence STX** soundcard (PCI-Express) connected, is there any hope of making it work inside the windows virtual machine it parallels?

By default it won't detect it ofcourse - http://take.ms/qgxZe - the card isn't showing up in Sound or Device manager and the installation process for the STX drives dies saying that it's not connected, though it IS connected, and works fine on a natural windows system booted from another SSD drive (I have dualboot).

I'm aware that the card itself is deadly incompatible with macs and it's not really designed to work that way but still, is there anything possible to play around to make it work inside a parallels virtual machine?

Comment: Does Parallels support PCI passthough? That way it would appear as a PCI(e) device in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a pretty long list of requirements to be able to do this at all.

Firstly, you need a processor with VT-D (or IOMMU, but that's for AMD processors, and no Apple hardware uses those), and a motherboard that supports this. I'm unsure if any 'official' apple hardware supports it at all, but its possible none of them do.

Secondly, you need a virtualisation software that supports passthrough, and these are typically KVM on linux and ESXi. I'm not aware of any that run on OS X.

With these two, and *proper* configuration, it *may* work - its more common to do this with GPUs rather than sound cards.

So, chances are, no, there's no way this could work.

Comment: yep, looks like this is goodbye for trying this, my intel core i7-3770k somehow DOESN't support VT-d (though the non-overclocking 3770 version DOES, which is kinda unlogical)

Comment: Actually, the amusing thing is I *have* a core i7 3770, which I bought cause I didn't need to overclock, and I wanted the option of passthrough.